# An infinite group with finite exponent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My Question is clear. I know that there exists infinite groups with finite exponent, But I want an example of such a group.

Any idea?

Comment: exponent of group G is the smallest number n such that for each g in G then $g^{n}$ = 1

Comment: @DietrichBurde, that link is not quite the same question, though one answer there works here too.

Comment: @lhf  Then [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2692124/a-group-g-is-finite-iff-all-its-elements-have-the-same-finite-order) is better. Anyway, I think one should first look for duplicates here.

Comment: Thank you ... There are very elegant solutions

Comment: \The question is more interesting if you ask for finitely generated examples.